# How to configure mod_reqtimeout in Apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, timeout, ddos

I need to configure mod_reqtimeout in my Apache server v2.2.22 (in a linux machine). Problem is, I have absolutely no clue on how to do it.

I checked the Apache site on this module at this link but there was no clear download/configuration details given. Can someone help me on this ? Any help is much appreciated.

Basically:

- Is there something needed to download ?
- If not, which files do I need to edit and how?

I can see a mod_reqtimeout.so file in my modules directory of apache.

Comment: Well read the documentation for Apache and mod_reqtimeout. If you couldn't find it it is here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_reqtimeout.html . If after reading that you have specific questions please re-edit the above question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To check if the module is loaded, you can use the command

`apachectl -M` or `apache2ctl -M`

, depending on your OS.
If it's not loaded, you can load it on Debian/Ubuntu systems using

`a2enmod reqtimeout`

, on CentOS/RHEL systems you will have to edit your `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`. Find the lines starting with `LoadModule` and add one like this:

```
LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
```

Make sure to restart apache afterwards. To configure it, you just add a line starting with

```
RequestReadTimeout
```

and the values you want to either your httpd.conf (global) or some VirtualHost configuration (just for the vhost).